# How is an elastic beanstalk instance associated with route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have taken over an AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup that uses Route 53. I have added a new EB instance and want to point the Route 53 settings to it rather than the instance it is currently pointing to.

My problem is I do not understand what settings to use.

In the EB dashboard my new instance is called xxx.newinstance.elasticbeanstalk.com.

I can't find any reference in Route 53 to the instance it currently points to which is xxx-oldinstance.elasticbeanstalk.com. In Route 53 there are references like s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. but nothing that seems to relate to a specific instance.

What do I have to do to make Route 53 point to my new instance?

Comment: It might help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Comment: Yes I have looked at that but it doesn't give the information i need about Route 53

Comment: Route 53 has nothing specific, just use Elastic Beanstalk URL as a CNAME record

Comment: I cant see where to do this. All I can see in Route 53 is references to S3-website-eu-west.... I can't see any references to an EB instance URL

Comment: Well, if you see that it means that website is hosted on AWS S3, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 3):

Go [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) and read the section titled "**To view the Elastic Beanstalk URL for your application**". Use those instructions to find and copy your application URL.

Now go into Route53 and create a new CNAME record for your domain. Enter the Elastic Beanstalk application URL as the "value" of the CNAME record.

Note that you are just using Route53 as a standard DNS service here. The instructions would be the same if you were using any other DNS service such as Godaddy, etc.

Comment: Yes I have seen this document, and know how to get the url, my problem is with how to change the existing Route 53 settings that are supposed to point to an existing EB instance. In the current Route 53 settings I cannot see any reference to the instance URL (only to S3-website-...). If I could find the URL ref in Route 53 I would simply change it to the new instance. Where is the CNAME record in Route 53?

Comment: The title of your question seems to be a bit different than your actual question. If the subdomain that points to the website in question is pointing to S3 instead of EB, then you need to look into what is in that S3 bucket. Someone might have configured an S3 redirect to EB as a way to point a root domain to EB. Or you could be mistaken about the site being hosted on EB.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at S3. The site is definitely on EB. Where in S3 would I find the redirect? All I can see is a list of buckets and what they contain.

Comment: In the S3 web console: right-click the bucket in question -> Properties -> Static Website Hosting.

Comment: I checked that and there is no mention of the elastic beanstalk url of my instance

Comment: There isn't anything magic going on here, this really should be simple to track down. First identify the URL for the website, then identify the DNS record that is used for that URL, then check where that DNS record points to.

Comment: Yes indeed, this should be trivial and if this was all on a conventional server I would sort this out no problem. As far as I can see the domain name is pointed to Route 53 and Route 53 does not appear to mention the EB instance URL. This reference must exist somewhere it is just I can't see where.

Comment: I have discovered that Route 53 was using an elastic ip address to refer to the instance so I created a new elastic ip for the instance I want to move the domain to point to but sadly this didn't work (connection times out so I am doing something wrong). Anyway I am getting closer!